# Split Based on... different options not working for me?

Tags: split, twilio, ivr

Under the English_gather flow, when I click 2 or 3 on the caller pad, it keeps going to the first option. Not sure why?

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure to update your flow?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the wrong variable in that Split widget. If you look closely you can see you are testing against `{{widgets.Welcome.Digits}}` and it should be `{{widgets.English_gather.Digits}}`.